# How to export SVG file from Photoshop so that I can edit it?

Tags: html, css, svg, web, photoshop

In my layout (.psd) I have svg file. How can I to export him so I can paste him in html and edit from css? When I click on the "Export as" and choose "svg", it is exported as shown below.

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="75" height="22" viewBox="0 0 75 22">
  <metadata><?xpacket begin="" id="W5M0MpCehiHzreSzNTczkc9d"?>
<x:xmpmeta xmlns:x="adobe:ns:meta/" x:xmptk="Adobe XMP Core 5.6-c142 79.160924, 2017/07/13-01:06:39        ">
   <rdf:RDF xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#">
      <rdf:Description rdf:about=""/>
   </rdf:RDF>
</x:xmpmeta>
                                                                                                    
                                                                                                    
                                                                                                    
                                                                                                    
                                                                                                    
                                                                                                    
                                                                                                    
                                                                                                    
                                                                                                    
                                                                                                    
                                                                                                    
                                                                                                    
                                                                                                    
                                                                                                    
                                                                                                    
                                                                                                    
                                                                                                    
                                                                                                    
                                                                                                    
                                                                                                    
                           
<?xpacket end="w"?></metadata>
<image id="logotype-white-mobile.svg" width="75" height="22" xlink:href="data:img/png;base64,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"/>
</svg>
```

and I can't change it (for example, change the fill from white to red in the hover). And when I click on "export contents...", it's exported as .ai file. Help me please. (Sorry for my English)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have the latest Photoshop--

1) Move that shape / object to it's own layer
2) Right click on the layer, select Export As
3) A export modal should pop up, select SVG 
4) Open the SVG file in a code editor
5) Copy the SVG code, paste in your HTML where you want it
6) Style fill color in CSS